# Is it possible to use different overlay on the same buffer that showing in different window?

Tags: emacs, window, overlay, buffer, elisp

So far, as I know, overlay in emacs should be associated with a specific buffer. And, *IF I UNDERSTAND CORRECTLY*, only one overlay to a specific buffer can work.

Currently, I meet a problem like this. What I want is to make the different windows show different things via overlay.

Of course, the thing goes easily when different buffer is showing. But the problem comes out when the two windows are showing the same buffer.  For example, I apply OL-A and OL-B to a buffer BUF-FOO. But when WIN-A and WIN-B are showing the BUF-FOO, either OL-A or OL-B can work. But I want to make OL-A work in WIN-A and OL-B works in WIN-B.

So my question is just like the title showing : Is it possible to use different overlay on the same buffer that showing in different window?

The answer possibly is **NO**, although I don't wish.
So, could you give me some suggestion or work around about such scenario?

Comment: I've never written any overlay code but, if the mechanism suits your purposes, **indirect buffers** would most likely solve that problem. `C-h i g` `(elisp) Indirect Buffers` `RET`

Comment: Thanks so much, I will try that. And it seems this is just want I want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are talking about overlay arrows, as in `overlay-arrow-position`, or actual overlays as in `make-overlay`?

You can definitely have several overlays in a buffer (if they apply to the same spot, they may partly hide each other, tho for display-related properties, you can set the `window' property of an overlay to make it apply only to a give window, so that you can have different windows show the buffer differently).